# ASP.NET MVC 5 oAuth using Tumblr

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, tumblr, owin

Are there any Owin providers for Tumblr? Like [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter/) for Twitter or [Owin.Security.Providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/) for LinkedIn, GitHub, etc.

I need to implement OAuth2 Sign-on using several services including tumblr. I found Owin providers for all services except Tumblr. Did anybody work with same problem?

Comment: I need an OWIN Tumbler provider as well. Denis, did you find an implementation or roll your own?  BTW, Tumblr is OAuth 1.0a; most other APIs are using OAuth2 which is easier to implement.  Flickr is still OAuth 1.0, so I was going to look at this https://flickrowinsecurity.codeplex.com/ for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is now:

```
PM> Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers.Tumblr
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers.Tumblr/